# How to import another python file after terminating

Tags: python

This an image recognition code that allows a user to login and use another Python script. If the face is recognised break the face detection and then allow the logged in user to access another Python script. The code must not run both, one should and then the other one starts. Below is the sample code

```
Login = 0
while True:
    # ...
    # code that sets Login = 1
    # ...

    if Login == 1:
        break 
        import file
```

Unfortunately, the code breaks without providing access to the other file, it just breaks and terminates the code. Please help me fix this.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the tab in front of the import statement to execute it after the break of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `import file` statement comes after `break`. Once `break` is reached, the loop in which it is located will be left, and lines that come after this `break` inside the same loop are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the break here

```py
    if Login==1:
        #break  # this makes the if clause to break and doesnt run import file
        import file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement breaks out of the `for` loop, therefore you need to use `import file` at the same level as `for` and `if` statement should be inside `for`

```
Login=0
while True: 
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):

        matches = fr.compare_faces(known_face_encondings, face_encoding)

        face_distances = fr.face_distance(known_face_encondings, face_encoding)

        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            Print("successfully loged in")
            Login=1
        if Login==1:
            break 
    import file
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to switch the needed function before the break since it exits completely and abandons the rest of the loop

```
  if Login==1:
         
        import file
        break
```